# Update no actualiza listado en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

He estado tratando de actualizar mi tabla usando PHP, pero al ejecutar el código no se actualiza el listado. El código en PHP es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'] ?? "";
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'] ?? "";

if($codigo){
    include 'conexion.php';
    if($conexion){
        
        $consulta="update agregados set estado='0' where codigo=? and cantidad=?";
        if($stmt=mysqli_prepare($conexion,$consulta)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"si",$codigo,$cantidad);
            
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $output="Filas actualizadas: ".mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
            }else{
                $output="Error ejecutando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
            }    
        }else{
            $outPut="Error preparando la consulta: ".mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }
        
        mysqli_close($conexion);
    }else{
        $output="No hay conexion";
    }
}else{
    $output="Codigo vacio o no valido";
}

echo $output;
?>
```

La idea de la consulta sería poder eliminar un item especifico del listado, y además cabe aclarar que si el estado es 0, es que dicho registro quedó "eliminado", en caso de que el estado sea 1, entonces se muestra en dicho listado

Comment: Cuando mecionas que no se actualiza ¿Simplemente no hace nada el script o manda alguno de los errores que estás detectando en el script?

Comment: ¿Qué imprime tu código actualmente?

Comment: Lo que hace actualmente mi código es que dice "Filas actualizadas: 0", y por ende el listado no se actualiza

Comment: Con lo cual no sé si es un problema de la consulta o si es otra cosa

Comment: @StephanieRM Desconocía que se podía poner un parámetro para identificar un string, perdón por una respuesta incorrecta.